# How to programmatically turn ViewController into a UITableViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I currently have a `MatchCenterViewController` that I want to programmatically turn into a UITableViewController. I've attempted to do so below based on tutorials I've found, but it doesn't seem to be appearing.

MatchCenterViewController.m:

```
#import "MatchCenterViewController.h"
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface MatchCenterViewController () <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>
@end

@implementation MatchCenterViewController

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"newFriendCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"newFriendCell"];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    //etc.
    return cell;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

@end
```

Comment: Why you don´t extend UITableViewController ?

Comment: You can add a UITableView and add delegates of UITableViewController

Comment: Guys, why do you downwote this question without explaining why you are doing so? It is perfectly "legal" using any object, not only view controllers, as data source or delegate for the table view. That is why apple introduced the related protocols instead of insisting on subclassing some table data source super class or so. UITableViewController is just some sort of convenience class. Nothing more and nothing less.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a minimum, you need to implement the following methods

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

And you need to set the delegate and datasource, typically in `viewDidLoad`

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.tableView.dataSource = self;
    self.tableView.delegate = self;
}
```

Also, you need an `IBOutlet` to the table view if the table view was created in storyboard, or a property for the table view, if the table view was created in code.

Comment: + add a property for the table view.

Comment: @0x7fffffff you don't really need to add a property for the table view. Without, of course, self.tableView would not work. But if the table is added in IB/Storyboard editor and if the view controller is connected there as data source and delegate, then all the data source and delegate protocol methods would hand in a reference to the tableView which can be used quite nicely with each method.

Comment: Thanks all, I added a note to the answer concerning the connection to the table view.