# Text not being displayed in cells

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Trying to get my app to display text in its cells. Been scratching my head for a while. This is the code used to display the text but nothing appears. Any advice?

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"leftMenuCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    }

    if (indexPath.section == 0) {
        NSArray *titles = @[@"Quick Glance", @"Your Home", @"Invites"];
        cell.textLabel.text = titles[indexPath.row];
    }

    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Give _[this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23703817/how-to-programmatically-turn-viewcontroller-into-a-uitableviewcontroller/23703921#23703921)_ a look and see if it helps.

Comment: The problem is not in the code you've posted.

Comment: Did you hook up the dataSource for the tableView? BTW: You are using old APIs. In iOS 5 and newer you don't need to check whether cell is nil, because its automatically created for you.

Comment: @KaiEngelhardt that is only true if you're using registered cell classes or nib files (prototype cells in a storyboard are implicitly added as registered nibs)

Comment: @David You're right, I forgot that :D

Comment: As @CrimsonChris stated, it's unlikely that the problem is actually in the code you have here.  Post the rest of your `UITableViewDataSource` implementation and verify that you have your tableView data source and delegate properly set.

Comment: Can you show us what your - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section looks like please?

Answer (score 0):

If you have not add the following code in ViewDidLoad() method, please do so.

```
self.tableView.dataSource = self;
self.tableView.delegate = self;
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you should break this out differently so that you are not re-creating your backing store every time you are producing a cell.

More code would be required in order to ascertain exactly what the issue but at minimum you could put the following in to verify this.

```
@implementation ViewController {
    NSArray *_titles;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    _titles = @[@"Quick Glance", @"Your Home", @"Invites"];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [_titles count];
}

 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"leftMenuCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    }
    cell.textLabel.text = titles[indexPath.row];
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    return cell;
}
```

This is the bare minimum you will need above in order to show some information in the tableview

Now the question is are you using a UITableViewController where it already has set the dataSource and delegate methods or are you using a UIViewController where the dataSource and delegate have not been set (either in code or through XIB or Storyboard)?

If you do not have the delegates set up you need to set them up either through the storyboard or through the code, and if through code and using UIViewController make sure you have a reference to the UITableView otherwise you will not be able to set the datasource.