# Configuring UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm trying to make a custom UITableView that will store a textLabel and detailLabel in each cell, but all the tutorials I find are for UITableViewController.  When I try to implement just the UITableView, I can't figure it out.

I actually will have 2 table views on this view controller.  It's almost like a webpage in layout, or at least how I want it.

2 tables, and be able to put anything I want inside each cell.  For some, a couple strings, for others, maybe 3 small images.

Here's a screenshot of what I want.  I just can't figure out how to configure the tableviews so I can put content in them.

Edit: Im on swift, just FYI, and now have the code below (minus screenshot).  It stalls and I get SIGABRT at the declaration of the cell, even though that was the default implementation.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

    if (tableView == self.topTableView) {
        // do stuff for the first tableView
        cell.textLabel.text = "Size"
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = "750.32MB"
    } else {
        //do stuff for tableView2
    }

    return cell
}
```

[image: Screenshot of what I mean]

Comment: What problem are you specifically running into?

Comment: I can't even figure out where to start with adding data to it since all the methods and tutorials out there seem to relate to UITableViewController and not just the tableView.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23703817) for information on the minimum implementations of the table view delegate and datasource protocols.

Since you have two table views, you'll need a way to determine which table view is asking for information. Note that the first argument to all of the table view delegate functions is a pointer to the table view itself.  You can compare that with the IBOutlet's to the table view to determine which table view is requesting information.

For example,

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView1;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView2;

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    if ( tableView == self.tableView1 )
        return 5;
    else if ( tableView == self.tableView2 )
        return 10;
    else
        return 0;   // should never happen
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The premise is the same in terms of the tableView delegate methods you need to implement.  Assuming you have connected the tableviews to your viewController in IB or storyboard or whatever, just make sure you set the viewController to be the delegate and dataSource of both tableViews, then you need your ViewController to be a UITableViewDataSource and UITableViewDelegate in your interface declaration.  Then be sure to implement the appropriate delegate methods and inspect the tableView to determine which one the viewController is working with at the time.

In your header file:

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource>
```

In viewDidLoad:

```
self.tableView1.delegate = self;
self.tableView1.dataSource = self;
self.tableView2.delegate = self;
self.tableView2.dataSource = self;
```

In your delegate methods, check which tableView you are working with, something like this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if (tableView == self.tableView1) {
    // do stuff for the first tableView
    } else {
    //do stuff for tableView2
    }
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: I am on Swift, just FYI but I was able to translate.  I now have (but stalls at) `func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
        
        if (tableView == self.topTableView) {
            // do stuff for the first tableView
            cell.textLabel.text = "Size"
            cell.detailTextLabel.text = "750.32MB"
        } else {
            //do stuff for tableView2
        }
        
        return cell
    }
`